# server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, authentication, go, mgo

The following is my MongoDB connection dial from GoLang. But it's returning a panic "*server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.*". My username, password, hostAddrs and dbName are correct. What am I missing here?

```
dbName: = os.Getenv("ENV_DBNAME")
userName: = os.Getenv("ENV_DBUSER")
password: = os.Getenv("ENV_DBPASS")
dbHost: = os.Getenv("ENV_DBHOST")
mongoDialInfo: = & mgo.DialInfo {
 Addrs: [] string {
  dbHost
 },
 Database: dbName,
 Username: userName,
 Password: password,
 Timeout: 60 * time.Second,
}
sess, err: = mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDialInfo)
if (err != nil) {
 panic(err)

}
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I faced similar error and added `--authenticationDatabase` parameter and it worked while we connecting to a remote MongoDB

Use the similar below format in your code :

```
$mongorestore --host databasehost:98761 --username restoreuser
--password restorepwd --authenticationDatabase admin --db targetdb ./path/to/dump/
```

Comment: I'm confused... what is the --authenticationDatabase parameter? the name of the database you want to access?

Comment: In my case I had access to only one db on server. So I needed to just add `-d <dbname>` option. No need of `--authenticationDatabase` for me

Comment: It is the right advice, but I had '%' sign in my password, and in the cmd.exe script the sign has disappeared. I had the same error =)

Comment: I had a ';' in my password!

Comment: My problem was using shorthands `-u` and `-p` even beside `--authenticationDatabase` in `mongoimport`. Replacing them with their long-form respectively ( `--username` and `--password`) along with the `--authenticationDatabase` solved the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Often we confused with  parameter in the mongoexport command with "Log-In" user.
The command expects "Database Username" not Log-in username.
This is one possibility to input wrong user name.
"Database Username" can be found in "Users" tab for a database

Comment: In my case, I was using my mLab password instead of the db password. Silly mistake but this answer helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 10):

I got my answer from this link: https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/mongodb-3-2-server-returned-error-on-sasl-authentication-step-authentication-failed/

Except for all answers above, the only unmentioned reason is that my password has a special character '$' in it. I think this is a very common practice to have special characters and this may trip many without this simple tip:

When using command line mongo/mongostat/etc.. Single quote your username or password that has special characters!

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thank you.

Comment: tl;dr "To solve the issue, simply single quote the password field." e.g. -p 'password'

Comment: Thank you, I had a `&` which was causing the issue

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 4):

`mgo` returns this error if `username`, `password` or `database` are wrong. Check your credentials twice. There are no other situations when you can see `Authentication failed` error message.

Comment: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: Yes this is correct way to implement connection. Here is working code https://gist.github.com/bearburger/718dec31746762684a7a512aed992a37 that connects demo DB.

Answer (score 3):

In my case specifying auth database and auth mechanism in uri did help

```
./mongoimport --uri="mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/labelDb?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1" --collection=repo_item --file=/tmp/repo_item.json
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you report seem the cause of the authentication fail is caused by a nil pointer, you should check the data before using them to create the connection

Comment: I dont know how the up-voter understood you, but I am sure I understood nothing from your answer. Mind elaborating more...?

Comment: Well after more than 1 year I don't know exactly what I was thinking. Probably my idea was the Golang application can't retreive one or more env_variable from the host.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while using a connection string from a Heroku app by means of the `--uri` flag. What solved it in my case was adding the database name with `-d`:

```
mongodb_uri="$(heroku config:get MONGODB_URI -a myapp)"
mongorestore --uri=$mongodb_uri -d heroku_7m41q4xs db/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using with dokku mongo:import . In my case I included dot(period) in my db name

You shouldn't include dot in your mongodb name when 'dokku mongo:create '
I've changed it to seunghunlee instead of seunghunlee.net
now this command works

```
dokku mongo:import seunghunlee < seunghunlee.net.dump.gz
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing both --authenticationDatabase & --ssl, so here goes the full syntax for importing a json file into a Mongodb collection over an Atlas cluster (into the primary shard):

```
./mongoimport --host mycluster-shard-00-02.d0b2r.mongodb.net:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --username TestUser --db Test --collection Messages --type json --file RAW.json --ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect your **MongoDB Atlas** to the **Golang Application**, the Connection function would be like this:

```
func getSession() *mgo.Session {

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}

    dialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs: []string{<add your MongoDB shards as string array> }
        Username: "<MongoDB  username>",
        Password: "<MongoDB  password",
    }
    dialInfo.DialServer = func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr.String(), tlsConfig)
        return conn, err
    }

    session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("DB connected")
    }
    return session
}
```