# Connecting to MongoDB from mongo shell and Robo 3T

Tags: windows, mongodb, robo3t, mongodump

All,

I'm new to MongoDB and I was pulled into it when the vendor who setup our website left which means I'm learning everything from basic with a strong SQLServer DBA background.

On our Dev **MongoDB V3.4.2** Windows installation, the vendor gave me a user named Monguser defined in admin with root as role and after they left I noticed Robo 3T as part of the installation.

When I try to connect via the mongo shell as below, I get an error with the message "Authentication failed". `C:>mongo --username monguser  --password mongold!234`. I tried connecting to it via the **Robo 3T** and I'm able to connect via the same login/password.

---

Also, I was asked to create a backup of a database and I tried the following but it failed with the error `Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed` for database `MiningDB`

`C:\mongodump --username monguser  --password mongold!234 --dbMiningDB`

But if I run `C:\mongodump --username monguser  --password mongold!234` then it backs up all the databases in the installation without returning any error.

In both the cases, why am I getting the error? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. From the below link I figured out that I need to include ***"--authenticationDatabase admin"***

[Referred Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744131/server-returned-error-on-sasl-authentication-step-authentication-failed)