# Error when trying to create dump of mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

i tried to create a dump of a mongodb database on remote server which is running centos,nginx,mongodb v4.0.18 using the following command..

```
mongodump --host localhost:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --username <uname> --password <password> --db <db> --out <path to dump>
```

but im getting the following error
`Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744131/server-returned-error-on-sasl-authentication-step-authentication-failed ?

Comment: @rfestag no....

Comment: Sorry, missed that you had `authenticationDatabase` in there. Another comment in there mentions the password having special characters. Have you tried quoting your password?

Comment: @rfestag i tried but its not working either

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced `--host localhost:27017` for `--port 27017`. My db is in localhost too. I omitted `--db <db> --out <path to dump>` too. I point to my db with the `--authenticationDatabase` flag.

I hope this helps.